# turning a project into a static library

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I checked out the microsoft documents. it shows how to create a static library upon creation of the project. but not necessarily on how to convert a previously made project, into a static library. So my question is, where do I go to turn my previously made project, into a static lib. so I can include it in my other projects

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Project | Properties -> Configuration Properties -> General -> Configuration Type (Static Library).

Comment: Yes.  Better remove main() or DllMain() definitions as well.

Answer (score 0):

1) See my comments on your previous question

2) `Properties - Configuration type - static library`